# using variable to change Parse.com query

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

I am using the following Parse.com Javascript query and need to switch the type of query based on a variable.

```
  function searchParseExercises (queryParam, ActiveFilters, searchParam) {
          var exercise = [];
          var TagSearch = Parse.Object.extend("Exercises");
          var query = new Parse.Query(TagSearch);
      query.containsAll("tags", ActiveFilters);

      query.limit(20);
      query.find({
        success: function(results) {
          var exerciseData = {};
          for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var object = results[i];
            var exerciseData = {
            exerciseName : object.get('exerciseName'),
            exerciseDescription : object.get('exerciseDescription'),
            images : object.get('images'),
          }
         exercise.push(exerciseData);
        }
         $scope.allExercises = exercise;
        },
        error: function(error) {
          $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: "Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message
            });
        }
      });
}
```

To clarify the requirement I have both a text search and filter search in my template. If there is a text search then it should perform:

```
query.contains("exerciseName", searchParam);
```

If there are ActiveFilters then it should perform this:

```
query.containsAll("tags", ActiveFilters);
```

However if both variables are present `(searchParam and ActiveFilters)`
 then it should perform a [Compound Query](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#queries-compound-queries).

I have no idea how I can wire all this up cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from your question:

```
if (ActiveFilters && searchParam) {
   Parse.Query.or(ActiveFilters, searchParam).find({
     success: function(results) {
         // results contains a list of players that either have won a lot of games or won only a few games.
     },
     error: function(error) {
         // There was an error.
     }
}
else if (ActiveFilters) {
    query.containsAll("tags", ActiveFilters);
}
else if (searchParam) {
    query.contains("exerciseName", searchParam);   
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. I need to have all eventualities
1. If text search only
2. Filters Only
3. Combination of both

Comment: It would be much better if you can edit your question and cite you requirement clearly. That way I would be able to help you in a much better way. Sorry, but again as per your last comment, I couldn't get the exact requirement.

Comment: See my updated answer, please feel free to ask any of your doubts.

Comment: The compound query does not work - I think that it needs the first part as per the docs?

Comment: Yes, it should be. The question was more related to changing scope variable. I haven't use parse ever so I can't tell you more on that.